# How to use the useState() with specific strings ("this" | "that")

Tags: typescript, react-native, use-state

I am trying to use the useState in React-native with TypeScript and want to use specific strings that can be used in a component. How can I do this?

I have this:

```
                                             |
                                             \/
const [getViewState, setViewState] = useState();
                 |
                 \/
<Icon name={getViewState} size={25} color={COLORS.light_gray}></Icon>
```

````
type props = {
  style?: StyleProp<ImageStyle>;
  name: "add" | "check" | "down" | "home" | "lock" | "right" | "search" | "settings" | "user" | "grid" | "list";
  size: number;
  color: string;
  onPress?: Function;
};```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood what you're trying to do, above where you've written the type for your Icon component's props, you can separate out the string type:

```js
type IconName = 'add' | 'check' | 'down' // etc.

interface IconProps {
  name: IconName
  size: number
  // etc.
}
```

And then, you can pass a type parameter to your `useState` call

```js
const [name, setName] = useState<IconName>('add')
                                    ^

<Icon name={name} size={25} color={COLORS.light_gray} />
```

Answer (score 0):

`useState` Accepts a Generic type.

`type MyType = "str1" | "str2"`

`useState<MyType | null>(null)`

Thus you can spicify what kind of state you want.

In your example:

```js
const [getViewState, setViewState] = useState<"string1" | "string2">("string1")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const [viewState, setViewState] = useState("myDefaultStateString")

<Icon name={viewState} size={25} color={COLORS.light_gray}></Icon>

// change state
const someFunciton = () => {
  setViewState("someOtherString")
}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.